# Understanding modifiable in Vim

Tags: linux, vim

During a OS upgrade (Linux), Vim or some part of it has been updated as well.

Now it happens that sometimes when I save a file (the file is not saved) I get this error:

> E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off

I did `:help E21` and the manual says:

```
        {not in Vi}     *E21*
When off the buffer contents cannot be changed.  The 'fileformat' and
'fileencoding' options also can't be changed.
Can be reset with the |-M| command line argument.
```

It's not clear to me what it means. I use and start the editor the usual way, nothing is changed. The workflow is the same, too. I open different windows with `CTLR-W N`, then load and edit files there and switch between windows, etc.

I'd like to know how to disable this behavior and about side effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:verbose set modifiable?` to find out if a plugin is setting the option. If the option has been modified by a plugin, it will show `Last set from /path/to/plugin/file` (in addition to showing the value).

Maybe you are using the Netrw plugin. It comes bundled with Vim and handles “editing” local directories (listing the contents, picking files to view/edit) and remote file/directory access. I know it twiddles `modifiable` (and some other options). There may be a bug in the version bundled with your updated Vim. You can check the version number of the active installation of Netrw with `:echo g:loaded_netrwPlugin`.

If the problem seems to be related to Netrw, you might try installing another [released version](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075), or maybe a [development version](http://drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW).

Comment: Thanks for the info. That was indeed a bug in Netrw. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/8K6qsQrpD5Y/MPQi5CHS89cJ

Answer (score 4):

This happens when you open a file that is read-only. Check the file permissions: it seems that your user doesn't have write permission on the file. Or maybe the filesystem is mounted read-only (check with `df /path/to/file` to see on what filesystem the file is, and use `mount` or `cat /proc/mounts` to see the mount options).

A different possibility would be a buggy decoding plugin, but then I'd expect other error messages.